# login_throttling with multiple user providers

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, symfony5, symfony-security

I have to use multiple user providers & firewalls in my Symfony 5.3 project.

I'd like to define login_throttling for every firewall.
With only one user provider and firewall everything works great ([based on documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#limiting-login-attempts)), but when I add second firewall and user provider I'm getting error:

[image: Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "login_throttling" listener on "main" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.]

My `security.yaml` below:

```yaml
security:

    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Seller:
            algorithm: auto


    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        sellers_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Seller
                property: email

    firewalls:
        main:
            # use a custom rate limiter via its service ID
            login_throttling:
                limiter: app.login_rate_limiter
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
        seller:
            custom_authenticator: App\SellerPanel\Security\SellerAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: seller_logout

framework:
    rate_limiter:
        # define 2 rate limiters (one for username+IP, the other for IP)
        username_ip_login:
            policy: token_bucket
            limit: 5
            rate: { interval: '5 minutes' }

        ip_login:
            policy: sliding_window
            limit: 50
            interval: '15 minutes'

services:
    # our custom login rate limiter
    app.login_rate_limiter:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RateLimiter\DefaultLoginRateLimiter
        arguments:
            # globalFactory is the limiter for IP
            $globalFactory: '@limiter.ip_login'
            # localFactory is the limiter for username+IP
            $localFactory: '@limiter.username_ip_login'
```

If I comment `login_throttling` key in `main` firewall I've got no error, but I'd like to use it in my project.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the problem, I should define pattern and provider for firewalls

My updated `security.yaml` below:

```yaml
security:

    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
        App\Entity\Seller:
            algorithm: auto


    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        sellers_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Seller
                property: email

    firewalls:
        seller:
            pattern: ^/seller-panel
            custom_authenticator: App\SellerPanel\Security\SellerAuthenticator
            login_throttling:
                limiter: app.login_rate_limiter
            provider: sellers_provider
            logout:
                path: seller_logout
        main:
            # use a custom rate limiter via its service ID
            login_throttling:
                limiter: app.login_rate_limiter
            pattern: ^/
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            provider: app_user_provider
            logout:
                path: app_logout

framework:
    rate_limiter:
        # define 2 rate limiters (one for username+IP, the other for IP)
        username_ip_login:
            policy: token_bucket
            limit: 5
            rate: { interval: '5 minutes' }

        ip_login:
            policy: sliding_window
            limit: 50
            interval: '15 minutes'

services:
    # our custom login rate limiter
    app.login_rate_limiter:
        class: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RateLimiter\DefaultLoginRateLimiter
        arguments:
            # globalFactory is the limiter for IP
            $globalFactory: '@limiter.ip_login'
            # localFactory is the limiter for username+IP
            $localFactory: '@limiter.username_ip_login'
```